# Speech to Text Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Have an app written that automatically reads out received text messages when they arrive.  Interested in perhaps a voice command that allows the receiver to speak a response - without touching the phone, which sends this string as a reply SMS.

Iv'e done some searches and seen some examples, but unsure of the complexity of integrating this feature into my app.  I placed the tts reader code (for the already working reader) in the onreceive method of the class that listens for received messages - which works well.  However, have no idea where to start with figuring out howto talk back at the phone, convert that audio data into a string, and firing that string off as a response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this project:

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-

After you understand that project, try this for more features:

https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib